# Can I use an IHttpModule insert markup before the closing HTML tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

If I write an ASP.NET HTTP module with the following event handler:

```
    void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app == null) return;

        app.Context.Response.Output.Write("<h1>FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h1>");
    }
```

Then I get something like this at the end of each response:

```
</body>
</html>
<h1>FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h1>
```

Is there any way to use the same approach but get my injected markup properly into the HTML document?

Comment: Why don't you use a master page?

Comment: If it is static you can have iis insert a footer. If it must be dynamic, you can use a master page as user2266486 has said or you can use a response filter (see here: http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters)

Comment: yeah i think response filter is what i'm looking for thanks!